# how to delete stored data in my application ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, download, swift2, ios9

hi in my app i am storing some data.
here is my code for downloading data

```
func downloadShow(slug: String, show: NSDictionary) {

    SVProgressHUD.showWithStatus("Downloading...")
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let url = NSURL(string: show["file"] as! String)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let showFileName = url?.lastPathComponent
            let programMP3Path = self.localURL + "/" + slug + "/" + showFileName!
            let programDataPath = programMP3Path + ".dat"
            data?.writeToFile(programMP3Path, atomically: true)
            show.writeToFile(programDataPath, atomically: true)
            print("Success")
           SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("Faulure: \(error)");
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

now i want to clear that particular data on the click of delete button. so how can i delete that data?

this is the path where i stored my data

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57EDF9A1-1108-4BA9-AE0A-57B8BA61869A/Documents/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use removeItemAtURL

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(urlDir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)
while let file = enumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(urlDir.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file Manager to delete your file, I've added obj-c Code,

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:YourFilePath error:&error];
```